# How can I get an output of one command as an argument to other linux command?

Tags: linux

I am getting process id for a process using:

```
ps -ef | awk '$8=="process name" {print $2}'
```

How can I use the output of above command as an input to the command below:

```
ps -p <pid> -o %cpu,%mem,cmd
```

Basically I needed the above two commands executed as a single command.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it to xargs:

```
... | xargs -I {} ps -p {} -o %cpu,%mem
```

The `{}` is the default argument list marker which can be used to send to your final command.

Alternatively you can also use command substitution

```
ps -p $(ps -ef | awk ...) -o %cpu,%mem
```